# Cannot access AWS EC2 instance from another instance via private IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

We have two Windows EC2 instances in the same subnet & VPC, created from AMIs shared via a different account. I've replicated the security group settings for each, and all seems fine.

However, we can not access shared folders/directories using the private IPs. We also cannot ping using the private IPs.

I've tried turning Windows firewall off for private networks, as well as leaving it and enabling the notifications. I even tried adding the IPs to the security groups out of desperation. Nothing seems to work, and I have no idea what else to try.

Any thoughts/tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can not ping VMs with private IPs from the external internet.
Create VPN Client and you will be able connect to the VMs and access the folders/directories.

If you are trying to ping vm which is in the subnet from the other which is also in the subnet make sure they are associated with the proper port in the security group.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about being RDC'ed into the boxes and going from one to the other. I ended up having to add the Security Group name for each server to the Security Group, (ex: sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXX)

Comment: @DigitalFusion Does this mean that you have resolved your issue? If so, you are welcome to add your own Answer.